# How do I put data I have received from a Http request into an array?

Tags: java, post

I need to insert post request data into array. I will get three sets of JSON information and I want to insert each JSON result in a String array. Here is the code I am currently using.

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/service.php");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
int i = 0;
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        arr.add(response.toString());
        System.out.println(arr.get(i));
        i++;
    }
```

If input like:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

This code outputs like:

```
abc
abcdef
abcdefghi
```

But I need output  like input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
```

to the first line in your 'while' block

Answer (score 1):

You have not reinitialized your `StringBuffer` variable response. In addition, you don't really need to use `StringBuffer`, since you are not manipulating the string information. I suggest you try the following (and at some point you won't want to use localhost):

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9090/service.php");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
int i = 0;
ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
   arr.add(line);
   // debug information
   System.out.println(arr.get(i));
   i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `arr.add(response.toString());` to `arr.add(line);` and it works.